# What is the different between "Console target" and "GUI target" in DCC32 option?

Tags: delphi

`DCC32.exe` has two options:

1. `-CC`: Console target
2. `-CG`: GUI target

Is there any different using these two options to build `dpk` and `dpr` files?

Comment: A Console target is a Console applications (for example a command prompt), whereas a GUI target is a forms application (for example VCL or FMX). This is without knowing anything about how DCC32 actually works or researching at all. A dpk file is entirely separate, and isn't either a Console or GUI application. It's not even an application. I'm assuming this pair of options is only available for dpr files and an exe target file. This makes me think though... Windows Services are apparently considered GUI apps...?

Comment: Look up Application Type or $AppType compiler directive in the documentation (Help File).  It provides information about the two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options control the subsystem of the output file. They only have meaning on Windows. They are equivalent to the [`$APPTYPE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_type_(Delphi)) directive.

> The $APPTYPE directive controls whether to generate a Win32 console or graphical user interface application.
>
> In the {$APPTYPE GUI} state, the compiler generates a graphical user interface application. This is the normal state for a Delphi application.
>
> In the {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} state (equivalent to the /CC command-line option), the compiler generates a console application. When a console application is started, the Input and Output standard text files are automatically associated with the console window.
>
> .....
>
> The $APPTYPE directive is meaningful only in a program. It should not be used in a library, unit, or package.